# Problem loading a XML file using Dom parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, nodelist

I am new with Java programming and I have problem reading XML-file. I am trying to save information from XML using DOM parser. I load the xml into a Document and then trying to save all the schedules of a radio channel in a NodeList. but the program saves repeatedly just infromation of the first node. Where is the problem with my code ?

```
   NodeList episodeElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("schedule");

    for (int i = 0; i < episodeElement.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = episodeElement.item(i);
        if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && getSize(doc) != 0) {
            Element e = (Element) n;
            String title = e.getElementsByTagName("title").item(i).getTextContent();
            NodeList nd = e.getElementsByTagName("description");
            String description;
            if (nd.getLength() > 0) {
                description = nd.item(i).getTextContent();
            }else {
                description = null;
            }
            String startTime = e.getElementsByTagName("starttimeutc").item(i).getTextContent();
            String endTime = e.getElementsByTagName("endtimeutc").item(i).getTextContent();
            Program prog = new Program(id, title, description, startTime, endTime);
            System.out.println(startTime);
            programs.add(i, prog);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No schedules found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you can show us an example of your XML, we will be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't used .getChildNodes() method to traverse a layer down the tag and looped around that, that's why it is just fetching you information of the first node.
Visit this link and u can find an excellent example.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HfGWVy-eMRc

Comment: Thank a lot for the help. i got what the problem is and i fixed it.